# Saving and adding back storage value when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this to-do list where the to-Do list is saved in local storage, but I do not know how to add the storage value back in the page where it was before when the page is refreshed.

JS:

```
    let inputField = document.querySelector('#inputField');
let submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit-btn');
let toDoList = document.querySelector('#toDoList');
let toDoItems = document.querySelector('.toDoItems');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.className = 'toDoItems';
    toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
    newLi.textContent = inputField.value;
    localStorage.setItem(inputField.value, inputField.value);
    inputField.value = "";
});

toDoList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.remove();
});
```

[What I have accomplished right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W76R.png)

Comment: You need to put the to do list items into an array and use `localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));` to store it. Otherwise you don't know which localStorage keys to read in the first place. If you do it with a single key, you can simply do `itemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo"));` to read them back and can populate the DOM from the array.

Comment: Push the entries to an array that is saved in local storage as JSON. `localStorage.setItem("ToDos", JSON.stringify([...prevTodos, newTodo]));` then `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ToDos")`. Then you can render the todos using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

So you have everything saved successfully, so now its just a matter of retrieving on load.

[This documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) outlines how to use the window's `load` event. From there, inside that listener you can retrieve the data and display it using something like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  let toDoString = localStorage.key(i)
  // Do something similar to submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){})
  // to create the list item and add it to the page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to store all the todoes in a single array, rather than as individual values. There are two reasons for this.

First, you can easily get and set the storage by using the same key.

Second, you can easily loop through and add them back, since they are already an array.

The example below won't work with local storage, as it's seen as not safe...
However, you should be able to copy the code and try it yourself.

```js
const inputField = document.querySelector('#inputField');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submitBtn');
const toDoList = document.querySelector('#toDoList');

const todoes = [];

function addTodo(todo) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.className = 'toDoItems';
  toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
  newLi.textContent = inputField.value;
  todoes.push(inputField.value)
  //! -- commented out to not cause an error in stackoverflow --
  // localStorage.setItem("todoes", JSON.stringify(todoes));
  inputField.value = "";
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

toDoList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.remove();
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
  //! -- commented out to not cause an error in stackoverflow --
  // todoes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getitem("todoes"));
  // todoes.forEach(todo => addTodo(todo));
});
```

```html
<input id="inputField" type="text" placeholder="What to do?" />
<button id="submitBtn">ADD</button>
<ul id="toDoList"></ul>
```